# Массив объектов typescript

Tags: html5, angular2, typescript

Приветствую !Нужна помощь!
Есть массив объектов : array=[{name:"vasy",age:33},{name:"pety",age:83}]

Как в angular2 передать переменные из этого массива в HTML код?

Comment: С помощью {{array[0].name}} или используйте цикл

Comment: Думаю стоит начать с туториала: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Вот здесь как раз и загвоздка.По одной переменной я понял как передавать.А вот с помощью методов или циклов не знаю. Я бы и начал с туториала,только срок у меня до завтра(

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let object of array"> {{object.name}} / {{object.age}} </div>` вот твой случай для шаблона

Comment: `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: "items-table",
  template: `

  <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td>Имя</td>
<td>Возраст</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{array[0].name}}</td>
<td>{{array[0].age}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{array[1].name}}</td>
<td>{{array[1].count}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
`


})
export class itemsTable [
 array=[{name:"vasy",age:33}
}`

Comment: Можете подсказать ,правильно?Если да,то как это сделать циклом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({ 
    selector: "items-table", 
    template: <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5"> 
                 <tr> 
                     <td>Имя</td>
                     <td>Возраст</td>
                 </tr> 
                 <tr *ngFor="let item of itemsTable "> 
                     <td>{{item.name}}</td> 
                     <td>{{item.age}}</td>
                 </tr>
              </table>` })
```

`itemsTable` переменная в классе компоненты

Comment: То есть *ngFor это аналог цикла и все теги и значения не надо вбивать самому?

Comment: Да, это не аналог, это и есть оператор цикла. Я не знаю какие вы языки изучали, но аналогия как ``forEach``. ``ngFor`` перебирает массив и в переменную ``item`` записывает очередной элемент.

Comment: Я java изучал))но javascript,html начал только на днях)))) Спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: Если ответ устраивает, пометь его как ответ на  вопрос.